# How does get_template_part() work inside a loop?

Tags: get-template-part

Could someone please explain to me how this function works inside a loop?

I've used this functions many times inside a wordpress loop like this:

```
loop start

  get_template_part("template/part", "example");

loop end
```

And the magic about this is that I can call functions like `the_title()` without any problem in template `part-example.php`.

But if I try to pass custom variables to `part-example.php` like this, it will fail:

```
$var = "variable";
Start loop

  get_template_part("template/part", "example");

End loop
```

And inside part-exmaple.php file

```
echo $var; // this will fail
```

I do find a workaround to solve this problem by reading great [this article](http://mekshq.com/passing-variables-via-get_template_part-wordpress/), it's using `include( locate_template() )`.

But I just wonder, how the post data get passed through by `get_template_part()`?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The post data are not actually passed to the template part. There is a global variable called `$post` which contains data about the current post, such as post's ID.

When you call a template part by using `get_template_part()`, the WordPress will look inside that template and run whatever is inside it, outputting it in the loop.

For example, if you use `the_title()` inside your template part, WordPress will try and run `the_title()` function, which depends on the post ID. However, since the global `$post` variable is available inside your template part, the call to `$post->ID` will be successful, and `the_title()` function will successfully print out the title of the current post.

If you want to pass some data to your template part, you can use `set_query_var();` instead. Consider a loop like this:

```
if (have_posts()) {
    while(have_posts()) {
        the_post();
        set_query_var( 'sample', 'sample_value' );
        get_template_part("template/part", "example");
    }
}
```

This will pass the sample to the template file, which can be retrieved by using this line of code :

`extract( $wp_query->query_vars );`

and then printed by:

`var_dump( $sample);`

I hope now you have some deeper understanding about how this feature works.

Comment: Thanks, I knew that all these `the_title()` stuff rely on `$post_ID`, and I also knew that we HAVE to declare the `$post` variable globally, but I didn't connect them together. Your explanation is great, cheers!

Comment: You are welcome. BUT, it's actually the `$post->ID`, not `$post_ID`. the `$post_ID` is a variable, while `$post->ID` is pointing to an object/array. Also, you don't need to declare the `$post` variable inside the main queries (such as home, archive,etc), but you might need to declare it inside the plugins or some functions. Anything else, please let me know. Cheers!

Comment: Yeah, what I want to say is that `the_title()` relies on the ID of `$post`, but I used a wrong way to explain that :) Thanks.